# Printing From Android to Mobile Bluetooth Printer with PhoneGap

Tags: android, printing, cordova, bluetooth

I'm new with PhoneGap but i know that it wraps web applications so that we can access native API's from javascript.

We are using Android as an embedded type of system and want to get it to work with the ADP400 BT printer.  This is a compact dotmatrix printer.  It seems like a great fit for a mobile device to use as a POS system.

However, I can't find any information on printing from mobile devices to BT printers using javascript.

Some printer manufacturers supply native API's for android, but is it possible to use such libraries from PhoneGap?

Any opinion will be appreciated,

Thanks,

Hakan

Answer (score 4):

You could wrap the native API's in a PhoneGap plugin to map the native API's to JavaScript. See the plugin examples [here](https://github.com/purplecabbage/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android).

Comment: Too bad, link down .. posted 3 years ago but still useful info

Comment: See https://github.com/purplecabbage/phonegap-plugins to find more recent history. Also, my personal phonegap-plugin fork still exists at https://github.com/paulb777/phonegap-plugins

Answer (score 3):

There is a plugin for PHonegap to handle [bluetooth devices](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/Bluetooth). It lacks proper documentation for new users but I hope you can figure your way out. If you have problem comment here I'll share the code which I implemented using the bluetooth example.

Good luck.

Comment: Hi Jay, link is dead, I can't judge how to find a new one.